# How to use Azure Data Factory, Key Vaults and ADF Private Endpoints together

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-keyvault

I've created new ADF instance on Azure with Managed Virtual Network integration enabled.
I planned to connect to Azure Key Vault to retrieve credentials for my pipeline’s source and sink systems using Key Vault Private Endpoint. I was able to successfully create it using Azure Data Factory Studio. I have also created Azure Key Vault linked service.

However, when I try to configure another Linked Services for source and destination systems the only option available for retrieving credentials from Key Vault is AVK Linked Service. I'm not able to select related Private Endpoint anywhere (please see below screen).

[image]

Do I miss something?
Are there any additional configuration steps required? Is the scenario I've described possible at all?

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE: Screen comparing 2 linked services (one with managed network and private endpoint selected and another one where I'm not able to set this options up):

[image]

Comment: you mean you ve created 2 linked services for AKV ? AzureKeyVault1 and AzureKeyVault2 and only AzureKeyVault2 is showing up ?

Comment: Did you select the managed vnet integration runtime ?

Comment: I'm able to select Managed vNet Runtime for my sink service. However on the linked service representing Azure Key Vault I cannot see the option to select runtime at all :(. I've added the screen comparing two linked services (one for Azure Blob storage with runtime and private endpoint selected and another one for Azure Key Vault where I'm not able to set this up.)

Comment: Ok, I will have a look and let you know. what are you storing in KV ?

Comment: Right now - nothing :). The plan is to store there connection strings and access credentials to the systems we'll be using during data flows processes (Azure Storage, Dataverse, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Managed Virtual Network integration enabled, Make sure check  which region you are using unfortunately ADF managed virtual network is not supported for **East Asia.**

I have tried in my environment even that option is not available

[image]
[image]

***So, I have gathered some information even if you create a private endpoint for Key Vault, this column is always shown as blank .it validates URL format but doesn't do any network operation***

As per [official document](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/azure-data-factory-and-key-vault/#:%7E:text=When%20configuring%20Azure%20Data%20Factory,%20you%20need%20to,select%20your%20Azure%20Key%20Vault%20and%20click%20create.)  if you want to use new link service, instead of key vault try to create other database services like azure sql, azure synapse service like as below

[image]

For your Reference:

[Store credentials in Azure Key Vault - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault)

[Azure Data Factory and Key Vault - Tech Talk Corner](https://www.techtalkcorner.com/azure-data-factory-and-key-vault/#:%7E:text=When%20configuring%20Azure%20Data%20Factory%2C%20you%20need%20to,select%20your%20Azure%20Key%20Vault%20and%20click%20create.)